# How can I filter a dictionary using LINQ and return it to a dictionary from the same type

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, linq-to-objects

I have the following dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int,string> dic = new Dictionary<int,string>();
dic[1] = "A";
dic[2] = "B";
```

I want to filter the dictionary's items and reassign the result to the same variable:

```
dic = dic.Where (p => p.Key == 1);
```

How can I return the result as a dictionary from the same type [`<int,string>`] ?

I tried `ToDictionary`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: In future, if you've tried the obvious approach but found it doesn't work, please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

`ToDictionary` is the way to go. It *does* work - you were just using it incorrectly, presumably. Try this:

```
dic = dic.Where(p => p.Key == 1)
         .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

Having said that, I assume you *really* want a different `Where` filter, as your current one will only ever find one key...